# Jquery show time based on selected date

Tags: jquery

I have a time range as the following.

```
{"Mon":"2.00 pm to 3.00 pm", "Tue":"10.30 am to 2.30 pm,4.00 pm to 5.00 pm"}.
```

In datepicker, whenever monday is selected, i need to show time in time picker as `2.00 pm. 2.15 pm,2.30 pm,2.45 pm,3.00pm.`

Similarly for Tuesday.
Can anyone please help me to show the time as mention using jQuery.